# Date from multiple strings in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have to generate one date (string or number) from two strings, the first of which is the day and the second the time. I must have made an error something in my code, because the result is different from the concatenation of the source data.

```
DIR4{h} = datestr(strcat(DIR1{h},' ',DIR2{h}),'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');
```

but:

```
DIR1{1} = 26/06/1998
DIR2{1} = 15:00:00

DIR4{1} = 17/03/0049 15:00:00
```

What's happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd executed every intermediate steps, you would have seen that `strcat` ignores trailing spaces ([as documented](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/strcat.html)):

```
strcat('26/06/1998',' ','15:00:00')

> 26/06/199815:00:00
```

The fix is rather easy: just don't use `strcat`, but rather use plain matrix concatenation:

```
strSrcDate = ['26/06/1998',' ','15:00:00']
```

Next you're using the wrong date conversion function. `datestr` is to convert tó a string, not from. Ok ok, it can handle string input, but that's [quite restricted](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/datestr.html#inputarg_DateStringIn). You'll want to use [datenum](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/datenum.html):

This gives a date serial (read the doc!), which is a number that represents a date (without any ambiguity). Use that number for internal storage of a date, and when you want to print that date out to screen or file, convert it to a string using `datestr`:

```
numSrcDate = datenum(strSrcDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS')

> 729932.625

datestr(numSrcDate,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS'); % or any other format
datestr(numSrcDate,'dd/mm/yy HH:MM');

> 26/06/1998 15:00:00
> 26/06/98 15:00
```

Answer (score 0):

The input to datestr must be a vector.

```
date(1,:)=[1998 6 26 15 0 0];
Sdate{1}=datestr(date,'dd/mm/yyyy HH:MM:SS');

Sdate =

26/06/1998 15:00:00
```